# Merging texts, reversing it, and other issues

Tags: c, text, merge

I want to start this by saying I do not want or expect you guys to 'do this for me', so to speak. I am basically just after some advice really - on where to start with this, the direction, etc?

I have been studying C for around 8 weeks now and feel so out of my depth. I enjoy it but am just awful at it. My mind doesn't seem to understand the logic like it does for some. I understand it eventually, but on functions week I was absolutely lost. Now we get this assignment (which is due in a little over two weeks) and I am utterly bewildered.

I would love to know how you guys would tackle something like this. I do just want to reiterate though, I do not want/expect you to do this for me. Just some advice would be greatly appreciated. Anywhere I am likely to trip up, etc, etc.

The project brief:

- You are required to write a single program that merges two input text files,
  one line at a time, and then saves the output to a new file – with the file contents
  reversed!
- The program should also produce statistics on the contents of each input file
  (number of characters, words, lines, etc.). These should be displayed on the
  screen.
- If one input file is shorter than the other then the remainder of the larger file
  should be added to the end of the output file.
- The user should be prompted to enter the filenames of the input files and output
  files.
- The program must be written in C within Microsoft Visual Studio.
  The Project
  What you are required to do:
  Deliverable 1
  Your program should prompt the user for the name of the two input text files to be
  read. It should then read in the files and display the separate file statistics on the
  screen.
  Deliverable 2
  Your program should now ask the user for the name of the output file. The program
  should then merge the files and write this to the named output file with the contents
  reversed. You should also submit a flowchart of the program’s operation and a
  description of the major variables in your program – what they do and what data
  they hold.

Answer (score 2):

Making the architecture is a very important part, take your time. Develop tests. Go step by step. Just 2-3 tips to help you.

- get the user inputs - you can do a getline or a read on 0 which is the standard input
- characterCount - you can use strlen, that counts char numbers in char*
- lineCount - you can increment an int in your getline loop, when you read the files, for example
- wordCount - strtok can help you with that AND the content reverse thing by the way

Comment: Thank you so much. This will be a huge help, I am sure. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just to give the idea of how to do it. The main part except the two file naming is following...

1. Open the text files
2. use a while loop to read the two files simultaneously
3. you can use odd even check of the loop so that you can read the files one at time e.g odd for textfile 1 even for textfile 2
4. you can use c = fgetc(fp) to read from the textfiles and fputc() to write every character to a new text file
5. use counter such that wordCount, characterCount,characterCount
6. wordCount increments whenever a space is checked if(c == 32)
7. characterCount increments with each character is read
8. lineCount increments whenever the '\n' character is read if(c == '\n')

this is the basic idea behind the construction of the program. i think you can make out the rest.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed. I really appreciate your input. Finding this task rather daunting. :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Microsoft Visual Studio as I code on Unix. The following should help.

```
- declare 2 variables as char * and allocate them (for 2 file names).
- declare 2 variable as char * and allocate them (for string buffer and the reverse)
- use scanf() in take input of filename.
- use fopen() to open these files.
- looping and use fgets() to get string for each line until EOF.
- use strlen() to get string length and count number of lines during loop.
- looping from length down to 0 to reverse the string.
- looping and use fputs() to write the string to another file.
- use fclose() to close both files
- use free() to de-allocate buffer
```

This is only my hints.